# Value of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+...}}}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, nested-radicals

I'm looking for the precise value of

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+...}}}}.$$

It has thus far resisted my attempts to find its value, and I was wondering if anyone could share some insight.

Comment: What is a numerical approximation?

Comment: A numerical approximation is 1.75793.

Comment: There is no known closed form for this expression. However, a value does exist. See the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: The [OEIS sequence A072449](http://oeis.org/A072449) has helpful information about the value.